# JQuery Mobile Page caching and data-dom-cache="false" still cached

Tags: jquery-mobile, caching, navbar

I have a navbar with 3 anchors and they are always cached, If I make a change to database once the page
has already been loaded, it does not reflect the changes if I move from 1 link to the other unless I reload the page...

I've put `data-dom-cache="false"` in both the page div and anchor, 
I don't know what else to do other than manually removing the page from the cache with javascript... Which I will only do as a last resort

The weirdest part for me is that If I bring up a popup with a link to these pages, it will reload...
But if it comes from the navbar, it doesnt work. (And it is NOT a `data-role="tab"` its just a navbar)

Please some insight!

Comment: The first page is always kept cassched that's why its not working. you can try (data-ajax=false) . If needed highjack the elemnets you need ajax -- http://api.jquerymobile.com/jqmHijackable/